# Parse Cloud function not found

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I call a function in Cloud Code, but this function doesn't work. The error in Xcode is:

```
[Error]: function not found (Code: 141, Version: 1.9.0)
```

This is the objective-c code:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            titleString,@"title",
                            descriptionString, @"description",
                            nil];

[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"saveNewItem"
                   withParameters:@{@"data": dictionary}
                            block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error) {

                                } else {

                                    NSLog(@"Error");

                                }
                            }];
```

The function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveNewItem", function(request, response) {

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var item = new Parse.Object("Item");
var title = request.params.data.title;
item.save({
        success:function (item) {
            response.success("Saved");
        },
        error:function (error) {
            response.error(error.message);
        }
    }
);
});
```

I read that it can happen if there is not the response success. But in this case there is.

The strange thing is that I have other similar functions that do not have problems.

Thanks

Comment: Did you define your cloud function in main.js ?

Comment: No, I have multiple file inside the Cloud folder. The main.js is empty. But the other functions work. I tried to move the function in the main.js, but it is the same.

Comment: Can you call your function via REST api ??

Comment: No, I use only the iOS sdk now

Comment: You can call your function via REST api as well. Test your function via Command line to make sure it is accessible: https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#cloud-code-cloud-functions

Comment: I did it and does the same error. If now I shift the function in main.js works.

Comment: You need to deploy all your functions to main.js first. Does it work in the app now ?

Comment: Thanks, must enter the require into the main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you split you code into multiple modules you need to import them in the `main.js` file.

So, edit you `main.js` file and use the `require` function:

```
require('cloud/file.js');
```